# How can I automatically scroll a scrollview with a scroller?

Tags: android, scrollview, scroller

I'm having trouble using a Scroller to scroll a ScrollView programmatically, so no touch gestures are involved in this so far. I want to scroll the ScrollView down at a certain speed, as long as data from a sensor is in a certain range. So basically I want to start scrolling the first time the data enters the valid range and then not disturb the scrolling process until the data is out of the range again. I don't want to connect the onSensorChanged directly to a scrollBy() because it will probably not work right on other devices. Here's what I've got so far:

in my onCreate:

```
tx = new TextView(ShowLyrics.this);
mainscrollarea = (ScrollView) findViewById (R.id.mainscrollarea);
scroller = new Scroller(getApplicationContext(), new LinearInterpolator());
tx.setScroller(scroller);
```

in my onSensorChanged:

```
if(integratedAngle - scrollTolerance > pointzero){ //this is checking for the data range and works so far
    if(!scrollingDown){
        scrollText("down");
        }
    }
```

and the scrollText function:

```
void scrollText(String direction){

    if(direction.matches("down")){
        scrollingUp = false;
        scrollingDown = true;           
        scroller.forceFinished(true);
        int currY = mainscrollarea.getScrollY();
        int endY = tx.getHeight();
        int distance = endY - currY;            
        scroller.startScroll(0, currY, 0, -distance, 5000);

    }

    if(direction.matches("up")){
    //nothing yet   
    }
}
```

So for now I've hardcoded 5 seconds for a scroll down, but nothing happens. A Log.d() of the Scroller's getCurrY in the onSensorChanged only spits out 0's. If someone could point me in the right direction, I would be thankful.

Answer (score 0):

I kind of do an automated scrolling like you. Except I rely on user input (when the user is near the edge of the screen with his finger, I start scrolling at a specific speed).

I use a runnable which does the same as the scroller will do.

```
private final DragScroller mDragScroller;

/** inner class */
private class DragScroller implements Runnable {
    private SCROLL_DIRECTION mDirection;
    private boolean          mIsFinished = true;

    DragScroller(Context context) {
    }

    void start(SCROLL_DIRECTION direction) {
        mState = STATE.DRAG_SCROLL;
        mIsFinished = false;
        mDirection = direction;
        post(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (mIsFinished) {
            return;
        }
        if (mDirection.equals(SCROLL_DIRECTION.UP)) {
            // check if the touch is still in the correct area...
            if (!isOverThreshold(0, mTempY, mDragScrollThreshold)) {
                scrollTo(0, ensureScrollBoundaries(getScrollY() - mDragScrollSpeed));
                post(this);
            } else {
                forceFinish();
            }
        } else {
            // check if the touch is still in the correct area...
            if (!isOverThreshold(getHeight(), mTempY, mDragScrollThreshold)) {
                scrollTo(0, ensureScrollBoundaries(getScrollY() + mDragScrollSpeed));
                post(this);
            } else {
                forceFinish();
            }
        }
    }

    public boolean isFinished() {
        return mIsFinished;
    }

    public void forceFinish() {
        mIsFinished = true;
    }
}
```

It is simply started by: `mDragScroller.start(SCROLL_DIRECTION.UP);` and can be stopped by `mDragScroller.forceFinish();`

**edit**

Based on your comment, you want to use the duration for the speed. This is kind of problematic because the resulting speed of the scroll depends on the distance you have to scroll in your given time. Short math sample: Scrolling 600px in 1 minute means you scroll 10px per second which is not that bad (depends on what you scroll, text or image...) but if you are near the edge and you need to scroll only 60px, the resulting speed depending on the given duration of 1min means very slow 1px per second.

Given that example you should base your scroll speed not on total duration but on pixel per second.

And yes, there is no need to use a Scroller for programmatically scrolling. Just the runnable which will call itself until it should stop and the speed can be adjusted to what ever you need...

Comment: If I understand this correctly you're repeatedly calling scrollTo, which has a fixed scrolling speed. I want to implement a user choice for auto scrolling speeds, so I need to change that, which is why I wanted to use the startScroll function that lets me specify a duration for the scroll. Additionally I can't see the Scroller you say is contained in your class.

Comment: Oh eh yeah, I only use the scroller to react on flings... sorry, I must have remembered wrong. The variable `mDragScrollSpeed` has the value of 10 which is pretty slow, but you can, of course, change the value based on you mentioned user input. I will update my answer a bit...